# bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to send the files from both side using socket communication . I have create an serverSocket object and create the connection . 
    client = serverSocket.accept(); 
Now i am able to sending the file from both side , but only one time . when i disconnect and reconnect it i am getting error: : bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

i have close the server socket and  client socket properly . but still i am getting this error ..

Can you please tell someone where i am doing mistake .

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                CommonMethods.e("File Async task port", "File Async task port-> " + PORT);
                // init handler for progressdialog
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket();

                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
                serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                Log.d(CommonMethods.Tag, "Server: Socket opened");
                client = serverSocket.accept();

                Log.d("Client's InetAddresssss  ", "" + client.getInetAddress());

                WiFiClientIp = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();

                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                        client.getInputStream());
                WiFiTransferModal obj = null;
                // obj = (WiFiTransferModal) ois.readObject();
                String InetAddress;
                try {
                    obj = (WiFiTransferModal) ois.readObject();
                    InetAddress = obj.getInetAddress();
                    if (InetAddress != null
                            && InetAddress
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(FileTransferService.inetaddress)) {
                        CommonMethods.e("File Async Group Client Ip", "port-> "
                                + WiFiClientIp);
                        SharedPreferencesHandler.setStringValues(mFilecontext,
                                "WiFiClientIp", WiFiClientIp);
                        CommonMethods
                        .e("File Async Group Client Ip from SHAREDPrefrence",
                                "port-> "
                                        + SharedPreferencesHandler
                                        .getStringValues(
                                                mFilecontext,"WiFiClientIp"));
                        //set boolean true which identifiy that this device will act as server.
                        SharedPreferencesHandler.setStringValues(mFilecontext,
                                "ServerBoolean", "true");
                        ois.close(); 

                        serverSocket.close();

                        return "Demo";
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {;
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Receiving...");
                        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
                        mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
                        mProgressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
                        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        mProgressDialog
                        .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                        mProgressDialog.show();
                    }
                };
                handler.post(r);
                Log.e("FileName got from socket on other side->>> ",
                        obj.getFileName());

                final File f = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                                + FolderName + "/"
                                + obj.getFileName());

                File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                if (!dirs.exists())
                    dirs.mkdirs();
                f.createNewFile();

                System.out.println("dirs==========="+dirs);
                /*
                 * Recieve file length and copy after it
                 */
                this.ReceivedFileLength = obj.getFileLength();

                InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();


                copyRecievedFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f),ReceivedFileLength);

                ois.close(); 
                serverSocket.close();

                this.Extension = obj.getFileName();
                this.EncryptedFile = f;

                return f.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                FileServerAsyncTask FileServerobj = new
                        FileServerAsyncTask(mFilecontext,FileTransferService.PORT); 
                if(!result.equalsIgnoreCase("Demo")){


                    try{
                        serverSocket.close();
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
                else{

                    if(FileServerobj != null) { 
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                            FileServerobj.executeOnExecutor (AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new String[] { null }); 

                        }
                        else FileServerobj.execute();

                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: please try to assign null may be it can solved your problem.

Comment: thanks for ans .. i did  but still same  error ..ois.close(); 
    serverSocket.close();
    serverSocket=null;
    client.close();
    client=null;

Answer (score 0):

This logic seems to be good. As far as it is asynchronous code - i would say the error is somewhere outside this code. Try to check if you are really closing connection **before** opening new one (so they don't overlap in time).

Comment: I bind and accept() the serverSocket two times ..first time to get the WiFiClientIp and all .. and again i bind to send the file to client and there i properly close the serverSocket .  I think the problem is here .. can i close the serverSocket from client side ..

Comment: You can't just close the server socket from client, but you can send from client some message (ex. "quit") and then if server receive such message - you can close it